# remove first and last quote from python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list

I have a list

```
list = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7']
```

I want my list as under:

```
desire output = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

how to get this, i read other similar answer where strip method used. i had tried strip but strip method not work with list, it work with strings.

```
'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Is it possible for this list to have more than one string? Like `['1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '8,9,10']`? If that's not possible, it's not clear why this is a list and not just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a `list` with a single `str` element. To get the list you want, try:

```
lst = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7']
>>> list(map(int, lst[0].split(",")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list-comprehension to split each item in the list, convert the sub-items to ints, and then flatten any sub-lists:

```
>>> my_list = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '8,9,10']
>>> [int(i) for sub_list in my_list for i in sub_list.split(',')]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```